# Boolean OR in condition - what's wrong?

Tags: php, boolean

Here's the condition -

```
if ($file !== "." || $file !== "..")
```

not working.

```
if (($file !== ".") || ($file !== ".."))
```

not working either.

```
if ($file !== ".")
```

works just fine. '
That really drives me edgy. I've read all that **php.net** has to offer on logical operators (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), a bunch of crappy tutorials I googled up, and I triple-checked the operator precedence. From all points, either of ways should work.

What could be the reason?

Comment: I'd bet, what you actually want is: `if ($file !== "." && $file !== "..")`

Comment: Are you looking for the AND operator (`&&`)? As in "if file is not equal to this AND not equal to this"?

Comment: your checking like '!==' instead '!=', is it right?

Comment: @deepi - `!==` is correct, it checks that the type of the variable is equal, not just the value.

Comment: @ James Allardice : OK, actually i don't know that, thanks for the information

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$file` should not be `.` AND it should not be `..`

`if ($file !== "." && $file !== "..")`

Comment: Yeah, my logic has failed me. Thanks.

Comment: Happens to me all the time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The expressions:

```
if ( $file !== "."  ||  $file !== ".." )
if (($file !== ".") || ($file !== ".."))
```

Will evaluate to true for every possible value for `$file`:

- for `.` the condition `$file !== ".."` returns true
- for `..` the condition `$file !== "."` returns true
- for `a` both condition `$file !== "."` and `$file !== ".."` return true

My be you want:

```
if ($file !== "." && $file !== "..") {
    // $file is neither . nor ..
}
```

Or vice versa:

```
if ($file === "." || $file === "..") {
    // $file is either . nor ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it always falling in to the true condition by any chance?  $file cannot be equal to to both "." and ".." so your conditions will always be true.  Don't you need an and instead of an or?